# False value in Where Clause Returns All Rows?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a query that looks like this:

```
`SELECT id, username FROM table_name WHERE username=0`
```

When I run this query MySQL returns all rows in table_name. Additionally, if I substitute 0 for false I get the same results. If I use null or an empty string then I get no rows returned (as expected).

The username column is varchar(50) if it makes a difference.

**My question then is this**:

Why does putting 0 or false in that query return all rows in the table? Is this a MySQL setting?

This worries me a little as I've been operating under the assumption that the above query would return no rows (in this particular case) and I wonder if this happening elsewhere in my application and what unintended consequences it might have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

username is being cast to an int of 0 to make the comparsion.  0=0 evaluates to true, so it's like there's no WHERE clause at all here.  You could use `username=''` if you're trying to get a non-null blank username.

Comment: It wont return any usernames that are null, only those that have a value.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. It isn't so much that I'm trying to get anything specific, the condition is arising when CodeIgniter substitutes an unset variable into the query. Thank you for the reply!